# Resizing WIndows partition and add it to Ubuntu partition?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I'm (unfortunately) running 3 OS's on a 128gb SSD. How can I make space for the Ubuntu partition (preferably from the Windows partition)?

Layout:

[image: layout]

Comment: ssd's require a certain amount of unallocated space to function properly and you are really pushing the limit. but if you absolutely have to do it. i would recommend minitool partition wizard FREE. It should be able to do what your after

Answer (score 0):

You can use **minitool Partition wizard FREE**.

Link:  https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

I used minitool Partition on a bootable USB to partition my hard disk for two operating systems. Check this link for how to do it:

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-partition-wizard-bootable-usb/

Although you have little space left, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your image, you `cannot` increase your Ubuntu partition by sacrifice your Windows partition. 
Because size partitioning can only increase/decrease its size to left/right. 
Example:

```
<Partition A= 1024MB> <Partition B = 500MB> <Partition C = 500MB>
```

You can decrease Partition A to 500MB (to right side), and give it to B.

But unfortunately, partitioning is way more complex, since you can't always do something like 
`Giving Partition B, and then resize Partition B and give it to C.`
It just doesn't work that way, sadly. Which you can't decrease Windows partition, and give it to `Unlocated 128MB (I'm pretty sure it's system-reserved partition)`.